# CKAN ERROR preview CSV , but OK for Download

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, ckan

I have the following error in my local test machine, just instaled.
Ckan, datapusher, datastore all in the same machine.

Accesing a csv resource i have the following message;
 "This resource view is not available at the moment. Click here for more information.

Could not load view: DataProxy returned an error (Data transformation failed. error: An error occured while connecting to the server: Unable to connect to server at URL: http://192.168.146.131/dataset/f2139e6a-7e22-41b1-97c2-51101dcfee2f/resource/015a5fc1-efac-49c8-9aff-82b04b0bdc93/download/MICSV.csv)"

Is a simple CSV for test burt cannot see
The URL is ok, i can access the resorce by copy/paste in the navbar. May be some thing in conf. I forget a plugin?

The modified lines in my conf file are:

```
sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://ckan_default:pass@localhost/ckan_default
ckan.datastore.write_url =     postgresql://ckan_default:pass@localhost/datastore_de
```

fault
    ckan.datastore.read_url = postgresql://datastore_default:pass@localhost/datastor
e_default

```
ckan.site_url = http://127.0.0.1
solr_url = http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr
ckan.storage_path = /var/lib/ckan/default
ckan.datapusher.url = http://127.0.0.1:8800
ckan.plugins = stats text_view image_view recline_view datastore datapus       her resource_proxy recline_preview
```

Answer (score 7):

The CSV preview uses the DataProxy, which is a service from the OKF (http://jsonpdataproxy.appspot.com/). This service downloads the CSV and parses its content. In order to work properly the resource must be publicly available. This means your CKAN instance must have a public IP and must be accessible from the internet.

My guess is that `192.168.146.131` is not your public IP, hence it doesn't work. If this is just an internal test system, it wouldn't work. You could run your own local instance of [dataproxy](https://github.com/okfn/dataproxy).

In the future, I would consider to [switch to the DataStore](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/datastore.html) or look at the new [Resource Views from >= CKAN 2.3](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/data-viewer.html).

Comment: The two links at the end of the answer seem not to be available any more.